# How to prevent right div from wrapping under the left div?

Tags: css, word-wrap

[see fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/CLErY/28/)

As I gradually resize the window from the right to left:

- red right box shrinks its width smaller and smaller ... ok
- 2nd green item goes under the 1st green item ... ok
- red right box and 2 inner green item goes under the blue left box ... not ok

I want the red right box to stay there with rest of behaviour unchanged.

Tried so many things, like `block: inline-block`, `min-width`, `white-space: nowrap`, none worked.

Please help!

(And could anyone explain why the red box wraps when there still so much space on the right side?)

Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`display: table` for the parent and `display: table-cell;` for the children is what you are after.

[Have a fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/CLErY/29/)

1. Remove the floats on `.left` and `.right` (leave the float on your green boxes)
2. Add `display: table` to `.wrapper`
3. Add `display: table-cell;` to your `.left` and `.right`
4. Add `vertical-align:top;` to your "table cells" so content is not vertically centred

CSS

```
html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
.wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    display: table;
}
.left {
    width: 25%;
    min-width:100px;
    height: 100%;
    margin:0px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
}
.right {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:top;
    width: 70%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.item {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    margin:20px;
    float: left;
    border:1px solid green;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I was looking for. First time I heard of `display: table` tho!

Comment: `display:table` can be overlooked often; maybe because there is such a stigma around the word `table` (as tables should not be used to layout your page) :)